# Jsoup: how to get an image's absolute url?

Tags: jsoup

Is there a way in jsoup to extract an image absolute url, much like one can get a link's absolute url?

Consider the following image element found in `http://www.example.com/`

```
<img src="images/chicken.jpg" width="60px" height="80px">
```

I would like to get `http://www.example.com/images/chicken.jpg`. What should I do?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Once you have the image element, e.g.:

```
Element image = document.select("img").first();
String url = image.absUrl("src");
// url = http://www.example.com/images/chicken.jpg
```

Alternatively:

```
String url = image.attr("abs:src");
```

Jsoup has a builtin [absUrl()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#absUrl(java.lang.String)) method on all nodes to resolve an attribute to an absolute URL, using the base URL of the node (which could be different from the URL the document was retrieved from).

See also the [Working with URLs](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/working-with-urls) jsoup documentation.

Comment: I've tried that, and it didn't work (returned an empty string), for some reason (unlike link.attr("abs:href") which worked)

Comment: That's odd. Can you post (or email me) a sample of it not working for you? I just added a passing test case to confirm it works: https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/commit/c659826cc45517535253fc59791fc53af95b5f9f

Comment: Sorry, after more investigation it was my fault. It works now, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @JonathanHedley Hi, I have problem in Url fetching, could you please answer my question at your confidence, Thanks in advance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36373775/canot-fetch-image-url-inside-specic-class-jsoup

Comment: When using jsoup doc with already fetched html, we must first set **doc.setBaseUri(..)** for it to work.

Answer (score 12):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("www.abc.com").get();
Elements img = doc.getElementsByTag("img");
for (Element el : img) {
    String src = el.absUrl("src");
    System.out.println("Image Found!");
    System.out.println("src attribute is : "+src);
    getImages(src);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume you are parsing `http://www.example.com/index.html`.

Use jsoup to extract the img src which gives you: `images/chicken.jpg`

You can then use the [URI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) class to resolve this to an absolute path:

```
URL url  = new URL("http://www.example.com/index.html");
URI uri = url.toURI();
System.out.println(uri.resolve("images/chicken.jpg").toString());
```

prints

```
http://www.example.com/images/chicken.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be inside a div class so the code would be like this (as example only)

```
System.out.println(doc.select("div.ClassName image").attr(src));
```