# Get a single image URL using JSOUP

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Im confused trying to get a single image url (url of product main image ) from this  [page](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01M2ZKBQE) with JSOUP. Im trying to do this different ways like below but seems somewhere I turn wrong)

```
Element element = page.select("div.imgTagWrapper").first();
imgUrl = element.attr("src");
```

Here is the final (little cuted) div child with wanted src.

```
<div id="imgTagWrapperId" class="imgTagWrapper" style="height: 342.857px;">
<img alt="Amanda Uprichard Women's Wren Maxi, Fluro Pink, S" 
src="https://images-na.ssl-images-    amazon.com/images/I/71jou38OlPL._UX342_.jpg" 
data-old-hires="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71jou38OlPL._UL1500_.jpg" 
class="a-dynamic-image  a-stretch-horizontal" 
id="landingImage" data-a-dynamic-image="{&quot;https://images-na.ssl-images-[740,569],&quot;https://images-na.ssl-images-[445,342],&quot;https://images-   na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71jou38OlPL._UX466_.jpg&quot;:[606,466]}" 
style="max-width: 264px; max-height: 342.857px;">
  </div>
```

Comment: You are selecting just the div, but you want the img tag inside the div. That's the one that has the src attribute.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4875064/jsoup-how-to-get-an-images-absolute-url