# Get src of a class nested in a class with Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup, src

I am a beginner at jsoup, and I would like to get the src of the image in this code:

```html
<div class="detail-info-cover"> 
<img class="detail-info-cover-img" src="http://fmcdn.mfcdn.net/store/manga/33647/cover.jpg? token=eab4a510fcd567ead4d0d902a967be55576be642&amp;ttl=1592125200&amp;v=1591085412" alt="Ghost Writer (MIKAGE Natsu)"> </div>
```

If you run it you will see the image I want to get.

Comment: I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4879865/11719787), which may help you

Comment: Thanks, Arvind Kumar Avinash, It worked and I marked it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String html = "<div class=\"detail-info-cover\"> \n"
                + "<img class=\"detail-info-cover-img\" src=\"http://fmcdn.mfcdn.net/store/manga/33647/cover.jpg? token=eab4a510fcd567ead4d0d902a967be55576be642&amp;ttl=1592125200&amp;v=1591085412\" alt=\"Ghost Writer (MIKAGE Natsu)\"> </div>";
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        Element image = doc.select("img").first();
        String imageUrl = image.absUrl("src");
        System.out.println(imageUrl);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
http://fmcdn.mfcdn.net/store/manga/33647/cover.jpg? token=eab4a510fcd567ead4d0d902a967be55576be642&ttl=1592125200&v=1591085412
```